# prevent page opening on an iframe?

Tags: php, iframe

How can I prevent page opening on an iframe using PHP? Like Gmail inside an iframe?

Answer (score 8):

For PHP, you can use.

```
header("X-FRAME-OPTIONS: DENY");
```

This is only supported in modern browsers, IE8+, Firefox 3.6.9, Safari 4 and Chrome. For older browser, you would also require some JavaScript.

Comment: Also header("X-Frame-Options:SAMEORIGIN"); to allow opening iFrames on the same domain only. If you are doing this for security purposes you may also add: header("X-XSS-Protection:1; mode=block");

Answer (score 6):

You can do that with JavaScript

```
if( (self.parent && !(self.parent===self))
    &&(self.parent.frames.length!=0)){
    self.parent.location=document.location
}
```

This will redirect from page that opens your page in iframe to your page.

Answer (score 4):

You cannot know from PHP code whether the current page is being loaded inside someone's iframe. PHP is run at the server, before anything is sent to the browser.

Only JavaScript, which runs in the browser, can detect if its window is the parent or not and do something about it.