# How to force all links to open in iframe

Tags: php, iframe, hyperlink

Is there a way of forcing every link to open in an iframe? I have control of some of the websites I want to show but not others. I am willing to use php or javascript.

Thanks

Comment: Related - [prevent page opening on an iframe?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4948168/prevent-page-opening-on-an-iframe)... people can prevent you from forcing them.

Comment: Check this plugin - http://www.no-margin-for-errors.com/projects/prettyPhoto-jquery-lightbox-clone/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $('a').attr('target', 'iframeNameHere');
});
```

[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/TfkkE/) little sample.

Comment: Would this go on the page with the iframe or on the page to be displayed?

Comment: @randomdev On the page displayed.

Comment: @randomdev added a sample. ;)